# href of anchor tag inside listview not fired

Tags: asp.net, listview, anchor

I have a listview which contain an  tag inside it, also it contain an href, but the href is not working. Here is the code

```
<asp:ListView ID="listsearch" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemsearch">
 <LayoutTemplate>
  <ul class="ada"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemsearch" runat="server"/></ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li>


      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("https://www.google.co.in") %> '  Text="Ssdsd"/>
       </li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

HTML output:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_listsearch_ctrl0_LinkButton1" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$listsearch$ctrl0$LinkButton1"‌​, "", false, "", "google.co.in";, false, true))' style="border-width: 1px;">Ssdsd</a>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML that this generates?

Comment: yes <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_listsearch_ctrl0_LinkButton1" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$listsearch$ctrl0$LinkButton1", "", false, "", "https://www.google.co.in", false, true))' style="border-width: 1px;">Ssdsd</a>

Comment: Why are you using `string.Format()` on a plain string?  Also, is Google really going to handle your WebForms POST request?  What do you expect to happen when you click on this link?  What does happen?  Are there any errors in the browser's JavaScript console?  Is a request made?  What is the response from that request?

Comment: dont get the result when using  PostBackUrl='https://www.google.co.in'

Comment: @David i need to open a page on new tab when click on the link

Comment: @DeepuT: Right, and what actually happens when you click on it?  Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a debugger.  Check your browser's debugging tools.  Any console errors?  Any request made?  Any response from that request?  At the very least, when you click this link that JavaScript function will be called.  You need to narrow down what happens and where it fails.

Comment: Perhaps you should use an actual anchor tag <a>

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:LinkButton>` control is intended for simulate the behaviour of an `<asp:button>` but in hyperlink taste. If you do not need server processing on click event better use `<asp:hyperlink>`  or simply non-server html `<a>` tag:

I guess you've a property like Url in the DataSource passed to the ListView, so you replace your LinkButton for something like that:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'
               Target="_blank"><%# Eval("myUrl") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Or better:

```
   <a href="<%# Eval("MyUrl") %>" target="_blank"><%# Eval("MyUrl") %></a>
```

And also opens the url in a new tab!

Comment: i am using the hyperlink in a listview. So that the link is not firing

Comment: if you ListView is inside a UpdatePanel (ajax) remember to include ClientIDMode="AutoID" in every asp.net control in ListView
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Target="_blank" ClientIDMode="AutoID"><%# Eval("myUrl") %></asp:HyperLink>